# Internet issues

Tags: internet

I recently updated the system and now am unable to connect to the Internet via WiFi or cable.

I suppose I should clarify that while it recognizes the connections it does not connect to the web.  All other connectivity is fine.

All other devices wired and WiFi within my home are fine and absolutely nothing has changed with my network settings whatsoever.

P.S. I do have the infamous Broadcom card in a Dell inspiron.

I've also booted to all previous Kernels and still nothing.

```
billy@BillyLaptop:~$ ifconfig 
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:1c:23:89:46:5f
        UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 
        RX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
        TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:7200 (7.2 KB) TX bytes:8654 (8.6 KB) Interrupt:21

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1 
        RX packets:2672 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
        TX packets:2672 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
        RX bytes:233285 (233.2 KB) TX bytes:233285 (233.2 KB)

wlan0   Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:1c:26:3a:65:aa
        inet addr:192.168.11.5 Bcast:192.168.11.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 
        inet6 addr: fe80::21c:26ff:fe3a:65aa/64 Scope:Link 
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 
        RX packets:2789 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
        TX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:365198 (365.1 KB) TX bytes:32067 (32.0 KB)
```

```
billy@BillyLaptop:~$ route -n 
Kernel IP routing table 
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface 
0.0.0.0 192.168.11.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 wlan0 
192.168.11.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 9 0 0 wlan0
```

```
billy@BillyLaptop:~$ nmcli dev list iface wlan0 
GENERAL.DEVICE: wlan0 
GENERAL.TYPE: 802-11-wireless 
GENERAL.VENDOR: Broadcom Corporation 
GENERAL.PRODUCT: Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card 
GENERAL.DRIVER: b43 
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION: 3.13.0-32-generic 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION: N/A 
GENERAL.HWADDR: 00:1C:26:3A:65:AA 
GENERAL.STATE: 100 (connected) 
GENERAL.REASON: 0 (No reason given) 
GENERAL.UDI: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/0000:0b:00.0/ssb0:0/net/wlan0 GENERAL.IP-IFACE: wlan0 
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED: yes 
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT: yes 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING: no 
GENERAL.CONNECTION: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2 CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT: no 
CAPABILITIES.SPEED: 48 Mb/s 
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0} 
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]: 58555ac2-5665-41c6-98db-633d44173cb7 | HarperBentley 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC: yes AP[1].SSID: 'TG862G12' 
AP[1].BSSID: 14:AB:F0:31:D1:10 
AP[1].MODE: Infrastructure 
AP[1].FREQ: 2462 MHz 
AP[1].RATE: 54 MB/s 
AP[1].SIGNAL: 50 
AP[1].SECURITY: WPA2 
AP[1].ACTIVE: no 
AP[2].SSID: '2WIRE322' 
AP[2].BSSID: B8:E6:25:26:7A:51 
AP[2].MODE: Infrastructure 
AP[2].FREQ: 2457 MHz 
AP[2].RATE: 54 MB/s 
AP[2].SIGNAL: 60 
AP[2].SECURITY: WPA WPA2 
AP[2].ACTIVE: no 
AP[3].SSID: 'HarperBentley' 
AP[3].BSSID: 00:24:A5:34:98:19 
AP[3].MODE: Infrastructure 
AP[3].FREQ: 2412 MHz 
AP[3].RATE: 54 MB/s 
AP[3].SIGNAL: 78 
AP[3].SECURITY: WPA WPA2 
AP[3].ACTIVE: yes 
IP4.ADDRESS[1]: ip = 192.168.11.5/24, gw = 192.168.11.1 
IP4.DNS[1]: 192.168.11.1 
IP4.DOMAIN[1]: satx.rr.com 
DHCP4.OPTION[1]: domain_name = satx.rr.com 
DHCP4.OPTION[2]: expiry = 1408997236 
DHCP4.OPTION[3]: broadcast_address = 192.168.11.255 
DHCP4.OPTION[4]: dhcp_message_type = 5 
DHCP4.OPTION[5]: dhcp_lease_time = 172800 
DHCP4.OPTION[6]: ip_address = 192.168.11.5 
DHCP4.OPTION[7]: routers = 192.168.11.1 
DHCP4.OPTION[8]: subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0 
DHCP4.OPTION[9]: domain_name_servers = 192.168.11.1 
DHCP4.OPTION[10]: network_number = 192.168.11.0 
DHCP4.OPTION[11]: dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.11.1
```

Thank you immensely for any and all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment (below 50 rep) so I had to ask here. Can you post your `ifconfig`  and `route -n` please? 
Also the following:

```
nmcli dev list iface wlan0
```

Assuming your interface is `wlan0`

**EDIT** Can you post the result of `ping google.com -c 2` ?

**EDIT_2** ok Seems like you are connected but DNS lookup fails. Assuming you are using `dhcp` Can you run the following:

```
sudo dhclient -v -r wlan0
sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

And post the output here and if you can access internet after it? If that didn't do it try

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down 
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Then try to reconnect to your *wifi* network

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't let me comment back wither

Comment: Maybe there's a text limit for comments I'm not sure

Comment: Ping: unknown host google.com

Comment: I've also removed my old kernel that went into kernel panic and Uninstaller reinstalled the driver for the Broadcom card and still nothing wired or WiFi